# Why Rspec cannot find the select2 method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, jquery-select2, rspec-rails, select2-rails

I've just joined a new company and when I'm using the `select2` method in Rspec, I get the following error: `` NoMethodError:undefined method `select2' for... ``

We use the `'capybara-select-2'` gem.

So I added in spec_helper.rb the following config: `config.include CapybaraSelect2` and it's perfectly works. Problem, when tests are pushed on heroku, it raises an error: `uninitialized constant CapybaraSelect2`.

The weird thing is my colleague doesn't need to add the config line for using this method...

Do you have any idea why he can use it without it and I can't? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My CTO finally found a way to make my code working:

I was calling `config.include CapybaraSelect2` at the end of `spec_helper.rb` so he moved it within `rails_helper.rb`, just as following:

```
config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
config.include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers
config.include ::Passwordless::TestHelpers::SystemTestCase
config.include CapybaraSelect2
```

Everything works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Your coworker probably did `gem install capybara-select-2` at some point installing it globally into his environment, while you're using it via bundler.  You should make sure it has been included into the `:test` group in your gemfile.

That being said I wouldn't recommend using that gem anymore, it hasn't been updated in years.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Thomas! We checked and we have the same version of `gem 'capybara-select-2'` and it is presents in `:test` in our gemfile. Related to your second point, there are in fact two different gems and one of them has been upldated recently (around one year), it has been built by @Hirurg103.

If you have another idea where this problem could come, I'm all ears :)